# What was the name of the turn-into-by-touching character in "The Last Starfighter"?

Tags: character, the-last-starfighter

The movie "The Last Starfighter" from 1984, featuring a kid getting sent on a mission by winning at a video game, had a character (a parasite?) which touched him, gave him a shock, and then after a few days or weeks of vegetating in bed became an identical copy of the kid.

What was the name and/or species of that character?

Answer (score 3):

The organism which turns into the main character was called a **beta unit** AKA **simuloid**. [This site](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0087597/quotes) documents this with the following quote:

> **Alex Rogan:** Hey, you look like me!
>       **Beta:** Of course I do. I'm a beta unit.
>       **Alex Rogan:** What the hell is a beta unit?
>       **Beta:** A beta unit is a simuloid. An exact duplicate, only not as loud!

Personally, I would have called it a haptoduplimorphoid (an android which changes into and duplicates what it touches). Anyways, this is arbitrary, too bad. If anyone knows of any other terms for this science fiction phenomenon then please let me know.

Comment: Very good, thanks. Your original question before it was edited was about "Star Wars" which is why I was more focused on relaying the actual film and not the precise nature of the duplicate. I've seen the movie a few times, I'm surprised I never caught that before.

Answer (score 1):

You're referring to the android duplicate named Beta in "The Last Starfighter" (1984).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That is what Wikipedia states about this individual, but these terms are so common easy-to-remember words nowadays (especially since the advent of android phones and statistics). I wonder if anyone would know what planet this organism is from (or any other attribute which would identify the organism nowadays in a more catchy manner).

Comment: Also, I would like to know which movies repeat this concept. I remember some Arnold Swartznegger movie about human cloning, not sure if this was the same concept, cannot remember.

Comment: @JackMaddington - 6th Day

Comment: He wasn't an android, he was a simuloid

Comment: So Wikipedia is wrong, perhaps someone can correct it. Was 6th Day his name, or did it take 6 days for the metamorphosis to complete?

Comment: It's referred to as a "beta unit" in the movie, IMDb and Wikipedia label it an android. There is a Last Starfighter wiki or two that coins the term "simuloid" which is not mentioned in the movie, and I'm not aware of any canonical source outside the actual film, so I don't know where it comes from, maybe fan fiction?

Comment: I stand corrected, it is referred to as a simuloid in the film.